# youtube-dl nodejs has issues Error: spawn EACCES

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, youtube-dl

I install nodejs module [youtube-dl](https://github.com/fent/node-youtube-dl) but I got error

> events.js:72
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>                ^
>   Error: spawn ENOENT
>    at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
>    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)

I tried install youtube-dl on windows and it worked. How can I fix it on nodejs. I use nodejs version v0.10.33

Thank so much.

Answer (score 0):

This should help to fix the issue: http://www.alfredforum.com/topic/4959-enoent-path-issues-bash-nodejs/